# Making CSS layouts with fewer selectors?

Tags: css, xhtml

What are the best practices for making CSS layouts with fewer selectors and fewer DIVs?

Fewer selectors means less HTML and CSS, which is easier to manage.

How can we avoid using too many class/other selectors?

Comment: That is a very broad question.  I don't know if there is an easy straightforward answer for this. Could you give more detail or a code snippet?

Comment: @RandomBen - I know it's a broad question and i'm just asking about best practices

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Sass (Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets)](http://sass-lang.com/).  It helps you write CSS that's leaner and more maintainable.

> Sass makes CSS fun again. Sass is CSS,
>   plus nested rules, variables, mixins,
>   and more, all in a concise, readable
>   syntax.

Comment: That doesn't really solve much though. You still have bad CSS in the end which can make things slower for users. And you'd still have to manage the bad HTML.

Answer (score 2):

See **[How to Develop with CSS](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html)**:

Among other topics there is how to:

- Minimize HTML Markup
- Minimize HTML—Contextual Selectors
- Let the structure of the document
  work for you.
- Minimize CSS
- Group Logically Related Styles
- Tables are for Tabular Data. Period.

Great resource and a must read for any developer as well as designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). It does in a way help you to minimize the amount of repetetive coding.

Comment: also he needs to know how to write less css

Answer (score 1):

> What are the best practices for making CSS layouts with fewer selectors and fewer DIVs?

There are three of these:

1. Don't add selectors until you need them.
2. Don't add `div`s unless you need them.
3. If you're not sure whether or not you need something, you don't need it.

> Fewer selectors means less HTML and CSS, which is easier to manage.

I know, right? The easiest page I ever managed had no selectors and no tags at all, and was in fact a text file!

> How can we avoid using too many class/other selectors?

Use tag selectors.

I know, I know... Some folks like to give everything classes, thinking to themselves, "I might some day want to make odd-numbered paragraphs bright red with a royal blue background, and it'd be a real shame if I had to go back and modify the markup first." But that's just silly - red on blue is horrible. Avoid adding classes until you need to; that is, avoid adding classes until you've used up all of the tags. HTML has lots of tags, so **use 'em**.